# android text in table gets cut off

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I've been looking for an answer to this for a long long long time.
I have the following code:

```
 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow106"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@drawable/b02_light_bar">

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button35"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/b02_play_blue" 
       />

     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
       >


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView20"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"
       android:text="@string/interaction2"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView21"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#41c4dd"
       android:text="@string/interaction2cont"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

And my text in textview21 still gets cut off if it is too long.
Anyone know how to solve this?
I promise you, I tried everything!

Comment: Can you put snap shot of the screen..that how its being cut or how you want it..!

Comment: image is here: http://postimage.org/image/sn250vbsn/
you can see that the blue string: choose a paired phone when more than one is in the car is cut off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have copied your code and string and yes the problem is there..

I got one solution for you and that's

Remove `android:padding="10dp"` from `TableRow` tag and apply that in the `LinearLayout` right under the tableRow.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow106"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@drawable/b02_light_bar">

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:padding="10dp" 
       >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button35"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/b02_play_blue" 
       />

     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
       >


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView20"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"
       android:text="@string/interaction2"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView21"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#41c4dd"
       android:text="@string/interaction2cont"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the attribute `android:maxLines="3"`

Change your textview to

```
 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView21"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#41c4dd"
   android:maxLines="3"
   android:text="@string/interaction2cont"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: This did not work. At the moment the text is all in one line. in other instances it gets truncated to 2-lines.
It only gets truncated properly when the text is a lot longer than the tablerow can contain. if the text is only 2 or 3 characters too long, it get's cut off.

Comment: must be something wrong with the view hierarchy. if i set
    android:layout_width="50dp"
the text is ok, but i prefer to not set the width in the xml, but let it be determined by the resolution of the phone

Comment: this is not acceptable for long text and not working anymore